# jQuery animate not working inside input event listener

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, event-listener, jquery-events

I have a simple html page with one text box. When it is clicked I want the page to scroll down. So I put an event listener on the text box and in it I use animate for the scrolling. But when I run this the scrolling is not happening...

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script >
        $(document).ready(function() {
                    $("input").focus(function() {
                      $("html, body").animate(scrollTop: $(window).scrollTop() + 400);
                    })
            });
   </script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you forgot `{ }`

```
$("html, body").animate({scrollTop: $(window).scrollTop() + 400} , 1000);
```